# Fetching specific data from file using java

Tags: java, eclipse, file

I have a file with data like

```
FileName : 105_IZMIR-REGRESSION-DEV-MAP-MANAGMENT.html
14 scenarios
2 failed, 12 passed
Failed scenario:
IZMIR-1623.001
IZMIR-1623.006
FileName : 105_IZMIR-REGRESSION-DEV-VOICE-MANAGMENT.html
```

I have written the following code to fetch the data between the two filenames in a single file. I want to enter the first two lines of the data(i.e. `14 scenarios 
2 failed, 12 passed`) in two different strings and the below 3 in one so that later I can insert this to SQL. How can this be achieved?

Code:

```
package com.Script;

    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    import javax.sound.sampled.Line;

    public class Script_Read {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("E:\\Result.txt"));
            boolean tokenFound = false;
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
               String line= scanner.nextLine();
                if (line.endsWith("IZMIR-REGRESSION-DEV-VOICE-MANAGMENT.html"))
                {
                    tokenFound = true;
                } else if (line.endsWith("IZMIR-REGRESSION-DEV-GUIDANCE-enter code hereVIEW.html")) {
                    tokenFound = false;
                }

                if ((tokenFound) && (!line.endsWith("IZMIR-REGRESSION-DEV-VOICE-MANAGMENT.html"))) {
                 System.out.println(lines);
                }      
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
        }
    }
}
```